While Loop Exits After Calling Function
I'm trying to do a db backup script using Bash.
When adding a "Resume" feature to the script, I do the following loop calling defined functions to do step by step (depending on the .lock file contents).
This is unexpected behavior since I have created a bunch of other scripts that follow the same logic on calling functions from a loop and they work correctly.
My guess is it has something to do with the ssh command which is the difference throughout all the other scripts, but I just can't wrap my mind around it…
LOCK=restore.lock
SERVER_BACKUP_FILE_NAME="backup"

...

show_help()
{
    ...
}

while getopts i:h opt; do
    case $opt in
        i) COMPANY_ID=$OPTARG;;
        h) show_help
    esac
done

...

backup()
{
    if [ ! -z $COMPANY_ID ]
    then
        log_echo "Creating company backup file from production..."
        sleep 5

        SOURCE_SERVER_IP=$(dig +short ${SOURCE_SERVER_HOST})
        REMOTE_CMD="~/repository/scripts/database/backup.sh -i ${COMPANY_ID}; exit;"
        ssh ${SOURCE_SERVER_USER}@${SOURCE_SERVER_IP} "bash -l -c '${REMOTE_CMD}'"

        SERVER_BACKUP_FILE_NAME="backup_${COMPANY_ID}"
    fi

    sed "/\<backup\>/d" -i ${LOCK}
}

download()
{
    ...
}

import()
{
    ...
}

# For some reason the backup() function breaks the while loop.
restore()
{
    while IFS= read -r FUNC; do
        eval $FUNC;
    done < ${LOCK}

    # After all the functions have been called, it means process is done, remove the lock file.
    rm ${LOCK}
}


# If there is no lock file, create one and add the function names to be read as a list in a loop in restore() function.
if [ ! -f ${LOCK} ]
then
    log_echo "Starting..."
    touch ${LOCK}

    echo "backup" >> ${LOCK}
    echo "download" >> ${LOCK}
    echo "import" >> ${LOCK}
else
    log_echo "Resuming..."
fi

# Calling main function that loops through the .lock file containing the function names
# to dynamically execute said functions.
restore


I don't see a for loop, but I do see a while loop using redirection, same as in the duplicate

Does the stream on stdin (which came from the while loop's done < ${LOCK} line) still get consumed if you comment out the ssh command?

@SottoVoce Yes, it is consumed if ssh is commented.

@muru Fixed it.
Yes the duplicate (which I could not find the previous 4 hours) seems to have the right answer.
